# Have input elements starting at different left and end the same rights

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm looking to have the right sides of input boxes aligned to the div width - 10px but start strait after each label.
Ideally using just css.
If I needed I guess I could use js / vue to calculate the container width and change the `element.style.width` of the boxes but I'd rather avoid that.

The `style="width: 85%;"` is what I'm looking to replace.

```
<div id="send-to">
    To: <input type="text" id="mail-send" style="width: 85%;">
</div>
<div id="host">
    STMP Host: <input type="text" id="mail-host" style="width: 85%;">
</div>
<div id="port">
    Port: <input type="text" id="mail-port" style="width: 85%;" >
</div>
```

In the screenshot the widths are hard coded

[image: Right Sides Aligned]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex to achieve it, see the example below

```css
.div-wrap{
    display: block;
    width: 85%;
}
.div-flex{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
input{
  width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrap">
  <div id="send-to" class="div-flex">
      To: <input type="text" id="mail-send">
  </div>
  <div id="host" class="div-flex">
      STMP Host: <input type="text" id="mail-host">
  </div>
  <div id="port" class="div-flex">
      Port: <input type="text" id="mail-port" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with using the table-cell layout. See working example below. I added a wrapper class, so it wont destroy the layout of your remaining elements.

```css
.field-wrapper > div > input{
  display:table-cell;
  width:100%;
}

.field-wrapper > div{
  width:100%;
  display:table;
}

.field-wrapper > div > p{
  display:table-cell;
  width:1px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.field-wrapper{
  width:250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-wrapper">
  <div id="send-to">
      <p>To:</p><input type="text" id="mail-send" style="">
  </div>
  <div id="host">
     <p>STMP-Host:</p><input type="text" id="mail-host" style="">
  </div>
  <div id="port">
     <p>Port:</p><input type="text" id="mail-port" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what u r expecting:

```css
.main {
  width: 450px;
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid black;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.main div {
  width: inherit;
  display: flex;
}
.main div input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="send-to">
    To: <input type="text" id="mail-send">
  </div>
  <div id="host">
    STMP Host: <input type="text" id="mail-host">
  </div>
  <div id="port">
    Port: <input type="text" id="mail-port">
  </div>
</div>
```